# Integrating Apache Camel with CXF based RESTful webservices : Need Advice

Tags: java, spring, cxf, apache-camel, cxfrs

I am trying to integrate my CXF restful webservices with apache camel. the requirement is  that when someone hits my webservice, i take the request parameters and connect to google or some service provider to search for results using the request parameters. 
lets say my webservice is  foo:bar and i want to connect to google after this foo:bar gets hit.
this means my camel route would be something like that :

```
     <camelContext>
            <route>
             <to uri:"cxf://bean://foo:bar/>
             <from uri="http://www.google.com"/>
            </route>
           </camelContext>

    is this understanding correct.. 
    i am pasting a section of my config xml for review ..




<jaxrs:server id="restContainer" address="/" staticSubresourceResolution="true">
<jaxrs:serviceBeans>
<ref bean="FooBar" />
</jaxrs:serviceBeans>
<jaxrs:providers>
<bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JSONProvider">
<property name="dropRootElement" value="true" />
<property name="supportUnwrapped" value="true" />
</jaxrs:providers>
<camelcxf:rsServer id="rsServer"
// this is the rest uri which is mapped to my resource class address="http://localhost:port/MyApplication/rest/foobar serviceClass="com.camel.example.FooBar" />
<camel:camelContext id="camelContext-1">
<camel:route>
<camel:from uri="cxfrs:bean:rsServer" />
<camel:to uri="http://www.google.com" />
</camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

Also apart from this i am getting following exception when i run my webservice :
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.Container$Listener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1666)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    ... 58 more
I dont understand why i get this, as i am using tomcat for deployment.

Comment: I have logged a JIRA so we in the future will provide an example out of the box with the Apache Camel distribution: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-5203

Comment: thanks Claus ... now it works.. i added all the jetty jars that i could find on net (version 8.0)..

Comment: Can you mark your own questions as answered now that you got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue , added all the jetty jars in my builpath. jetty version 8.0